# how to add pulse animation with one after other in css like traffic lights blinks continously

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have two circles with pulse animation infinite times. Now I need animating the circle one after another continuously with infinite times. I tried pulsation the circle infinite times. I have added delay animation but it is not working I don't why. Please kindly refer the code and help to achieve that functionality:

HTML:

```
<div class="inner">one</div>
<div class="inner1">two</div>
```

Css:

```
.inner {
     width: 74px;
     height: 74px;
     background: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     position: relative;
     text-align:center;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}
 .inner1 {
     width: 74px;
     height: 74px;
     background: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 50%;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
     50% {
         -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
         transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05) 
    }
     to {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
}
 @keyframes pulse {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
     50% {
         -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
         transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05) 
    }
     to {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
}
 .pulse {
     -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
     animation-name: pulse 
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same `class` to all circles for common properties. The only properties you need different for each is `animation-delay`.

You can use a small jQuery code to set that for any number of divs. I have created an example for 3 divs, but feel free to extend it.

```js
let els = $(".inner"),
  length = $(".inner").length

els.each(function(index) {
  $(this).css('animation-delay', (index / length) + 's')
})
```

```css
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  animation: pulse 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner">one</div>
<div class="inner">two</div>
<div class="inner">three</div>
```

Comment: thanks anurag but when I have added three circle I am not getting one by one. Like our signal lights continously one,two,three and again one,two,three like that. Kindly refer the below changes I have made
https://codepen.io/vsandeep2516/pen/KKdgQKB

Comment: @sandeepv You need to state everything in the question right from the beginning, whether you want it for 2 circles, 3 circles or 100 circles..

Comment: I am sorry @anurag

Comment: thanks a lot but may I know what is the index in js and how to give linear animation-delay

Comment: @sandeepv Added `linear` timing in the code..and index is actually the counter for your divs, eg if you have 3 divs, the count is 0, 1, 2 and we divide that by total number in order to get animation-delay for each div

Comment: @anruag I am getting small confusion the length will give total how many divs are there and what is the use of the index. It also will give a count of inner divs present in the HTML

Comment: @sandeepv I used `$(".inner")` selector so it only selects that class, even if there are inner divs. `$(".inner").length` is only length of divs with that class `.inner`

Comment: then what is the `index ` in the function `els.each(function(index) `

Comment: @sandeepv `.each()` is a loop which runs for each element, and index is the value at each iteration. You know about loops in JS?

Answer (score 0):

`animation-delay` is working:

```css
.inner {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

.inner1 {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 5s
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">one

</div>

<div class="inner1">two

</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Hans but when I have added three circle I am not getting one by one. Like our signal lightscontinously one,two,three and again one,two,three like that. Kindly refer the below changes I have made codepen.io/vsandeep2516/pen/KKdgQKB

Answer (score 0):

Only Add animation Delay= .5s; and reduce second animation time with 1s

HTML:

```
<div class="inner">one</div>
<div class="inner1">two</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
     width: 74px;
     height: 74px;
     background: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     position: relative;
     text-align:center;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin-bottom:20px;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}
 .inner1 {
     width: 74px;
     height: 74px;
     background: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 50%;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
     animation-delay: .5s;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
     50% {
         -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
         transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05) 
    }
     to {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
}
 @keyframes pulse {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
     50% {
         -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
         transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05) 
    }
     to {
         -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
         transform: scaleX(1) 
    }
}
 .pulse {
     -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
     animation-name: pulse 
}
```